# BWA-MEM single strand or doublestrand alignment

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, molecular-biology, dna, bioinformatics

In whole genome secondary analysis does BWA-MEM use a double stranded fasta reference or are reads aligned to only one, single stranded fasta reference?

Answer (score 1):

BWA-mem (like most aligners), takes a normal single-stranded fasta file (I've never seen one with both strands listed) and aligns to both strand.

Comment: This means that BWA-MEM takes into consideration the complementary strand of each single stranded read prior to alignment?

Comment: Yes, all normal aligners do this.